# Phone Links not working in iOS 9

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari, ios9

Mobile Safari in iOS 8 can telephone somewhere with [Phone Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html).

`<a href="tel:1-408-555-5555">1-408-555-5555</a>`

I've installed iOS 9 in iPhone, but the links not working. It seems these are ignored. Does anyone know solution or reason?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out this problem by myself. Actually, I've written the Phone Links in iframe, but this has been the cause of the trouble. In iOS 9 Phone Links is ignored in iframe.